# Extraction Microrna From Humans Plasm

Tags: organic-chemistry, extraction

My question is: what is the best way to extract micro RNA (miRNA) from humans plasma? Whether trizol is suitable, or should I use commercial kits? Thanks

Comment: This seems a question better suited for another SE site, such as biology or medical sciences SE.

Comment: See: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_method_of_microRNA_extraction

Comment: For commercial advice: https://www.thermofisher.com/se/en/home/references/ambion-tech-support/rna-isolation/general-articles/ten-ways-to-improve-your-rna-isolation.html

Comment: A comparison of approaches: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3871541/